# Check if a element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if an element is visible and play a song only when it is, using: a `trigger('click')` event handler.

Unfortunately, I can't get it working as expected.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here is my JavaScript code (jQuery):

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function () {
  if ($('a.icon-play').is(':hidden') == false) {
   $('#stop').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('#play').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Below is my HTML code:

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="player-home-video">
        <audio id="yourownlullaby-audio" src="uploads/downloads/Buenas%20%20Noches%20%3C?php%20echo%20$_POST['name'];%20?%3E.mp3"></audio>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail-home-video">
        <a href="#" id="play">
            <span class="icon-play preview-icon" id="play"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" id="stop">
            <span class="icon-pause preview-icon" id="stop"></span>
        </a>
        <img class="info" src="img/thumbnail-home-video.png" />
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share HTML Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('.overlay').on('click', function () {
 if ($('a .icon-play').is(':hidden') == true) { 
$('#stop').trigger('click'); 
} 
else 
{ 
$('#play').trigger('click'); 
} });
```

Your​ `if` should be the other way.